# icingaweb2 authentication php error

Tags: php, icinga2

Yesterday I added the below mpm config to httpd.conf and restarted Apache. I logged in and everything was fine. This morning Icingaweb2 auth is broken. I doubt the mpm module has anything to do with the php error but that's all I changed.

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers           20
    MinSpareServers        30
    MaxSpareServers        60
    ServerLimit            400
    MaxRequestWorkers      400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
</IfModule>
```

The error:

**ERROR - Icinga\Web\Form\InvalidCSRFTokenException in /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Form/Element/CsrfCounterMeasure.php:63**

```
#0 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Form.php(2280): Icinga\Web\Form\Element\CsrfCounterMeasure->isValid('437123420|1846b...', Array)
#1 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Form.php(1276): Zend_Form->isValid(Array)
#2 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Form.php(1150): Icinga\Web\Form->isValid(Array)
#3 /usr/share/icingaweb2/application/controllers/AuthenticationController.php(50): Icinga\Web\Form->handleRequest()
#4 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Action.php(507): Icinga\Controllers\AuthenticationController->loginAction()
#5 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Controller/Dispatcher.php(76): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('loginAction')
#6 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Front.php(937): Icinga\Web\Controller\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response))
#7 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/Web.php(389): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response))
#8 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/webrouter.php(109): Icinga\Application\Web->dispatch()
#9 /usr/share/icingaweb2/public/index.php(4): require_once('/usr/share/php/...')
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my browser was for some unknown reason appending about 1,000 characters to the server's authentication URI. I vaguely remember seeing something to do with tokens but I can't seem to recover the suspicious uri in my browser's history that caused this error.

ARGH